# How yo handle page refresh, using axios and reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I am in need of help understanding why is it that in my app, when i refresh the page, the app sends me back to the login page, even when the access token and refresh token is still valid?
My intention is for the app to stay in the same page.
I am using redux for state management and axios for server communication.
Is there something wrong with the interceptors or my navigation logic?

Note: cant use history or any other libraries, except the ones that are imported in the code

Below is the code:

```
// App.jsx
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Register from "./components/Register";
import Topics from "./components/Topics";
import Root from "./components/Root";
import Dashboard from "./components/dashboard";
import { Routes, Route, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { login, logout } from "./redux/actions/authActions";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import EmployeeList from "./components/EmployeeList";

function App() {
  const isLoggedIn = useSelector((state) => state.auth.isLoggedIn);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  // Function to handle user login
  const handleLogin = () => {
    dispatch(login());
  };

  // Function to handle user logout
  const handleLogout = () => {
    dispatch(logout());
    navigate("/", { replace: true });
  };


  return (
    <Routes>
      {isLoggedIn ? (
        <Route path="/" element={<Root onLogout={handleLogout} />}>
          <Route index element={<Topics />} />
          <Route path="employeesList" element={<EmployeeList />} />
          <Route path="register" element={<Register />} />
          <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
        </Route>
      ) : (
        <Route path="/" element={<Login onLogin={handleLogin} />} />
      )}
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
// axios.js
import axios from "axios";
import store from "../redux/store";
import { logout } from "../redux/actions/authActions";

let retryCount = 0;
const MAX_RETRY_COUNT = 3;
const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8083/api/v1";
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
});

const refreshAccessToken = async () => {
  try {
    const refresh_token = localStorage.getItem("refresh_token");
    const response = await axiosInstance.get("/auth/refresh", {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${refresh_token}`,
      },
    });
    const access_token = response.data.access_token;
    localStorage.setItem("access_token", access_token);
    return access_token;
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
      store.dispatch(logout());
      localStorage.clear();
      window.location.href = "/";
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
};

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
  async (config) => {
    if (!config.headers.Authorization) {
      const access_token = localStorage.getItem("access_token");
      if (access_token) {
        if (!config.headers) {
          config.headers = {};
        }
        config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${access_token}`;
      }
    }
    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    return response;
  },
  async (error) => {
    // 401 Unauthorized
    const originalRequest = error?.config;
    if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest?._retry) {
      // To avoid infinite loop
      if (retryCount < MAX_RETRY_COUNT) {
        retryCount++;
        originalRequest._retry = true;
        const new_access_token = await refreshAccessToken();
        originalRequest.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${new_access_token}`;
        return axiosInstance(originalRequest);
      }
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

export default axiosInstance;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because page refresh causing all states cleared. It's temporary memory. You have to store your credentials in persistent storage where browser refresh cant affect. Local Storage is considered anti-pattern, but in my opinion, it depends on how and what information is stored in it. Actually, aws cognito stores credentials in local storage.

If your credentials are already persistent, just rendering problem. I guess `isLoggedIn` has 'true', 'false', 'undefined', so if `isLoggedIn === undefined`, just return  like following.

```
useEffect(()=>{
   // take credentials and set value into redux-state which cause re-rendering. 
},[isLoggedIn])

if(isLoggedIn === undefined) return <div/> // empty page

return (
<Routes>
    <Route>.....your code here....
```